# Chaining bash scripts on gcloud shell with gsutil

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gcloud, gsutil

I built a series of bash scripts to run BigQuery jobs for a data pipeline. These scripts are saved in a google cloud storage bucket. I pipe them to sh using this:

```
gsutil cat gs://[bucket]/[filename] | sh
```

Basically there is no problem if I run this from command line, but once I try running this command from within a bash script, I keep getting file not found errors?

It doesn't seem like a PATH issue (I may be mistaken) as calling $PATH from within the script shows where gsutil is located.

Is this a permissions issue?

I'm running this from within google cloud console shell in my browser. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error on this line and not another line in the script?

Answer (score 0):

To start, try printing out the output (both stdout and stderr) of the `gsutil cat` command, rather than piping it to `sh`.  If you're receiving errors from that command, this will help shed some light on why `sh` is complaining. (In the future, please try to copy/paste the exact error messages you're receiving when posting a question.)

Comparing the output of `gsutil version -l` from both invocations will also be helpful. If this is an auth-based problem, you'll probably see different values for the `config path(s)` lines.  If this is the case, it's likely that either:

- You're running the script as a different user than who you normally run gsutil as. gcloud looks under `$HOME/.config/gcloud/...` for credentials to pass along to gsutil... e.g. if you've run `gcloud auth login` as `Bob`, but you're running the script as `root`, gcloud will try looking for `root`'s credentials instead of `Bob`'s.
- In your script, you're invoking gsutil directly from `.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/`, rather than its wrapper `.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil` which is responsible for passing gcloud credentials along.